# ¿Cómo ejecutar el explorador de windows 10 desde php?

Tags: php, windows, windows10

Estoy necesitando abrir el explorador de windows 10 desde mi código php. Necesito hacerlo en el servidor. He probado lo siguiente:

```
<?php echo exec('explorer.exe); ?>
```

Pero esto funciona cuando el sistema operativo de mi servidor web es windows 8.1 o menor, en windows 10 se queda cargando y no se ejecuta.

Imagino que sea por motivos de seguridad, pero no si estoy en lo cierto o no, ni como solucionarlo.

La pregunta sería como abrir el explorarador en windows 10 desde código php...

Gracias a todos de antemano...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar necesitas invocar a tu programa con la ruta completa:

```
<?php exec('"C:\Windows\explorer.exe"'); ?>
```

Es muy probable que tengas el servidor web corriendo como servicio y este tenga restringido invocar programas del escritorio (GUI). En tal caso, tendrías que habilitarle la opción *"allow desktop interaction" / "permitir interacción con el escritorio"* a al servicio del servidor web/php

Los pasos para habilitar los permisos de acceso a otras aplicaciones para un servicio serían los siguientes:

**- Abrir administrador de servicios:**

[image: Abrir administrador de servicios]

**- Seleccionar el servicio en el cual se requiere activar la opción, hacer clic con el botón derecho del ratón y seleccionar la opción propiedades:**

[image: Seleccionar el servicio en el cual se requiere activar la opción, hacer clic con el botón derecho del ratón y seleccionar la opción propiedades]

**- Seleccionar la pestaña "iniciar sesión" y posteriormente habilitar la opción "permitir que el servicio interactúe con el escritorio:**

[image: Seleccionar la pestaña "iniciar sesión" y posteriormente habilitar la opción "permitir que el servicio interactúe con el escritorio"]

Comment: En tu pregunta original, ocupas la función echo antes de exec, eso es incorrecto, lo correcto sería usar exec sin echo como puse en mi ejemplo...

Comment: Efectivamente el problema está en que tengo Apache como un servicio, cómo podría habilitar "allow desktop interaction" ??? Estoy usando XAMPP.. Gracias por la ayuda...

Comment: Amplié la respuesta con los pasos necesarios para habilitarle el acceso al servicio al escritorio.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar cuando habilito eso para Apache, incluso reinicie la PC por si las dudas y nada. Con el servicio deshabilitado si funciona. ¿Conoces algun otro motivo por el que no funcione, o algo que esté haciendo mal? Saludos...

Comment: Quitaste "echo", dejando el script así?
<?php exec('"C:\Windows\explorer.exe"'); ?>

Comment: Sin activar el servicio me funciona de ambas maneras, pero habilitando "allow desktop interaction" lo probé justo como usted me recomendó, sin exito...